# Почему нельзя захватить глобальную переменную?

Tags: c++, лямбда-выражение, clang, дизайн-языка, лямбда-выражения

```
int x = 42;
auto f = [x]() { return x; };

int main(){ f(); }
```

> error: 'x' cannot be captured because it does not have automatic
> storage duration

Почему нельзя захватывать глобальные переменные?

Comment: Там же написано `because it does not have automatic storage duration`

Comment: А этого и не нужно, она и так доступна ...

Comment: @user7860670 вопрос в том, почему там так написано

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Локальные переменные захватывают, потому что у них нет постоянного места в памяти (адрес может быть разный при каждом вызове функции, которая их создает), их может быть больше одной штуки (при рекурсии), они могут неожиданно исчезнуть (при выходе из функции), и т. п.

А для глобальных переменных захват не нужен, поэтому и не разрешается. К ним можно обращаться без захвата. Не нужен, потому что они всегда существуют ровно в одном экземпляре, всегда в одном и том же месте в памяти.

Если очень хочется иметь в лямбде копию переменной, то начиная с C++14 можно написать `[x = x]{return x;}`.

Comment: ¿Почему не нужен-то? Если к ним обращать без захвата, то и значение в них может после захвата поменяться. Захват из примера вполне себе полезный сценарий. А вот wtf вроде `[x = x]` точно не нужно.

Comment: @user7860670 Не нужно - в том смысле что к ним технически возможно обратиться без захвата. К локальным невозможно.

Comment: Такая логика могла бы как-то работать, если бы захват был по ссылке, а при захвате по значению никто и не собирается обращаться к глобальной переменной.

Answer (score 3):

Ну, она везде (в том числе и в лямбде) доступна и так, но если ну *очень* хочется, то...

```
int x = 42;

auto f = [x=x]() { return x; };

int main()
{
    cout << f();
}
```