# Неявный захват константы

Tags: c++, лямбда-выражение

```
#include <iostream>

void bar(int x) { std::cout << x << '\n'; }

void foo() {
    const int x = 42;
    [](){ bar(x); }();
}

int main() { foo(); }
```

Почему программа компилируется, если `x` -- константа, и не компилируется в противном случае?

> error: 'x' is not captured

Comment: видимо ответ такой же как и в случае статической переменной. Нет смысла захватывать ее, она же константа.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1317313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут дело тонкое.

`x` - неявно `constexpr`, потому что она `const`, имеет целочисленный тип, и инициализируется константой времени компиляции. ([`[expr.const]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4) и выше)

Использование `constexpr` переменных в лямбде требует захвата только если вы используете адрес переменной (и переменная не глобальная и не статическая). Если вы используете только значение, а не адрес, в захвате нет необходимости. ([`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/11`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-11))

Такое использование адреса `constexpr` переменной называется *odr-использованием* (*odr-use*) переменной (от слова one definition rule), и делает захват обязательным. Для не-`constexpr` переменной даже ее использование без взятия адреса считается odr-использованием, поэтому их захват обязателен в любом случае. (вроде бы [`[basic.def.odr]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#4), но там на эльфийском, на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) понятнее)

Интересно, что если в лямбде указан захват по умолчанию - `=` или `&`, то даже не-odr-использование переменной в лямбде может вызвать ее захват, если компилятор это не соптимизирует, хотя в отсутствие `=` и `&` все работало бы без захвата. (пример в [`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-example-4))

Comment: Тут наверное не в константности дело. А в статической области хранения переменной `x`. Например компилируются такие : `static int x = 42;` , `const int x = 42;` , `constexpr int x = 42;`. И неявно компилятор сделал эти константы статическими.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Не-а, у него не статическая область хранения. Потому что вот это не работает: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q1Knhejqz